# How do you OrderBy in C# and LINQ using a parameter defined in runtime for a List<dynamic> where each dynamic is an ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, sql-order-by, expandoobject

I have a data that is generated at runtime and stored as a `List<dynamic>` called "Reports".

"Reports" contains many "Report" which are also generated at run time as a new `ExpandoObject().`

Each "Report" is assigned various properties (e.g. Report.Name, Report.Value, Report.Order, etc) at runtime before being added to "Reports".

The user is able to select which property they want to view (which are pre-defined).

I want to use LINQ OrderBy to sort "Reports" by the user defined property.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast to `IDictionary<string, object>` and use square bracket indexers with the property name string, e.g.

```
dynamic report1 = new ExpandoObject();
report1.Name = "Foo";
dynamic report2 = new ExpandoObject();
report2.Name = "Bar";

var reports = new[] { report1, report2 }.ToList();    

var sortBy = "Name";

var first = reports.OrderBy(x => ((IDictionary<string, object>)x)[sortBy]).First();

Console.WriteLine(first.Name); // Bar
```

Comment: Thank You!I just had to make sure every value in the ExpandoObject was a double - without this it wouldn't work.